# How can I drop consecutive row duplicates with condition of a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates) has been really helpful for getting the basis of what I want to do, however, I'm stuck with how to get to the finish line.

I have large dataframe (approx. 10k rows) with the first few rows looking like what I'll call df_a:

```
zone  | value   
0     | 12
1     | 12
2       99
3       12
0       12
1       12
2       12
3       99
```

I am looking to drop consecutive duplicates within 'value', however, based on the condition of zone. For example, in the above snippet I would want the second '12' to be dropped for zone = 1. So that I end up with:

```
zone  | value   
0     | 12
1     | 12
2       99
3       12
2       12
3       99
```

My initial idea was to use a loop across a list of zones, create new variables for each created zone automatically based on the zone name, and the run my drop duplicates code (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847803/splitting-csv-file-based-on-a-particular-column-using-python/58267676#58267676). However, this doesn't work:

```
data_category_range = df_a['zone'].unique()
data_category_range = data_category_range.tolist()

for i,value in enumerate(data_category_range):
    data_category_range['zone_{}'.format(i)] = df_a[df_a['zone'] == value]

   # de-duplicate
   cols = ["zone","value"]
   de_dup = df_a[cols].loc[(df_a[cols].shift() != df_a[cols]).any(axis=1)]
```

(This loop is within another loop which will iterate across dataframes with different 'zone' values, so variable needs to be dynamic - open to alternatives as I understand this isnt best practice).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {"zone": [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], "value": [12, 12, 99, 12, 12, 12, 12, 99]}
)
data.drop_duplicates(["zone", "value"])
```

This will give you

```
|    |   zone |   value |
|---:|-------:|--------:|
|  0 |      0 |      12 |
|  1 |      1 |      12 |
|  2 |      2 |      99 |
|  3 |      3 |      12 |
|  6 |      2 |      12 |
|  7 |      3 |      99 |
```

Comment: Apologies, a poorly worded question by me as the actual datasets are much larger (10k+ rows) and I understand the proposed `drop_duplicates` will only keep unique values? While I am aiming to remove **consecutive** duplicates (in my dataset, this represents no change, but it is still logged). Thanks!